How to bound the VC dimension of a new function class?
I have been looking into learning theory, and there is a particular problem regarding bounding VC dimension of a function class that I find to be interesting but difficult.
Assume  is a binary-valued function class, and the functions in  map the input space  to {0,1}.
The VC dimension of the function class  is .
Based on , I construct a new function class
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad=\{_:^2→\{0,1\}|_(_1,_2)=\min\{(_1),(_2)\},∈\}$.
How can I derive a tight upper bound on the VC dimension of the function class ?
Is it possible to show that VC(G)$\leq2⋅$?
If not, what is the tightest bound?
I have been thinking about this problem for a long time. Using Sauer's Lemma, I can show that VC(G)$<5⋅$, but I didn't find that satisfactory since this is not tight. Is it possible to prove a tighter upper bound for this problem?

Since $F$ is a collection of binary-valued functions, each $f\in F$ can be associated with a set in $X$: $A_f = { x\in X: f(x)=1}$.  Is the VC dim of $F$ equal to the VC dim of the collection of sets: ${ A_f: f\in F}$?  If this is the case, then you are also asking about the VC dim of ${ A_f\times A_f: f\in F}$, subsets of the product space $X\times X$.  Is that correct?  I'm more familiar with VC dim of sets than I am with functions.

Yes, you are right. Are there any existing result on the VC dim of ${×:\in }$?

I'm not sure at this point.  How do you use Sauer's Lemma to get $VC(G)<5d$?  I'm only seeing the more obvious bound $VC(G)\leq d^2$.

Assume $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)...(x_k,y_k)$ can be shattered by the function class $G$. Using Sauer's Lemma, the function class $F$ can achieve at most $(2ek/d)^d$ many possible labelings on 2k different inputs $x_1,y_1,...,x_k,y_k$. Therefore, the function class $G$ can also achieve at most $(2ek/d)^d$ many possible labelings on k different inputs $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_k,y_k)$. Therefore, $(2ek/d)^d \geq 2^k$. Using this inequality, you can show that $k<5d$.
